# making a stacked barchart in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart, stacked

I would like to create a stacked bar plot from the following dataframe:

```
   VALUE     COUNT  RECL_LCC  RECL_PI
0      1  15686114         3        1
1      2  27537963         1        1
2      3  23448904         1        2
3      4   1213184         1        3
4      5  14185448         3        2
5      6  13064600         3        3
6      7  27043180         2        2
7      8  11732405         2        1
8      9  14773871         2        3
```

There would be 2 bars in the plot. One for `RECL_LCC` and other for `RECL_PI`. There would be 3 sections in each bar corresponding to the unique values in `RECL_LCC` and `RECL_PI` i.e 1,2,3 and would sum up the `COUNT` for each section. So far, I have something like this:

```
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)    
sub_df = df.groupby(['RECL_LCC','RECL_PI'])['COUNT'].sum().unstack()
sub_df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
```

However, I get this plot:
[image]

Any idea on how to fix it? I am doing something wrong with the `groupby`, but not sure of the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've put data shown in `stackpandas.dat`. Given those data:

```
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = read_table("stackpandas.dat"," +",engine='python')

df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
sub_df1 = df.groupby(['RECL_LCC'])['COUNT'].sum()
sub_df2 = df.groupby(['RECL_PI'])['COUNT'].sum()
sub_df = concat([sub_df1,sub_df2],keys=["RECL_LCC","RECL_PI"]).unstack()
sub_df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,rot=1)
plt.show()
```

... gives:
[image]

... which I think is what is sought.

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151364/datetime-stacked-bar-chart-with-matplotlib-from-dataframe). Could kindly help me please?