# Stacked bar plot by grouped data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Let's assume I have `pandas` dataframe which has many features and I am interested in two. I'll call them `feature1` and `feature2`.

`feature1` can have three possible values.
`feature2` can have two possible values.

I need bar plot grouped by `feature1` and stacked by count of rows with each value of `feature2`. (So that there will be three stacks each with two bars).

How to achieve this?

At the moment I have

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['feature1'][df['feature2'] == 0].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',label='0')
df['feature1'][df['feature2'] == 1].value_counts().plot(kind='bar',label='1')
```

but that is not what I actually want because it doesn't stack them.

Comment: What about `stacked` argument in [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)?

Comment: `stacked` also doesn't work

Comment: isn't it what you want ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22787209/how-to-have-clusters-of-stacked-bars-with-python-pandas

Comment: @jeanrjc Sort of, but not exactly. I needed plot such as in given answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not sure how to do this in matplotlib (pandas default plotting library), but if you are willing to try a different plotting library, it is quite easy to do it with Bokeh.

Here is an example

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
x = pd.DataFrame({"gender": ["m","f","m","f","m","f"],
                  "enrolments": [500,20,100,342,54,47],
                  "class": ["comp-sci", "comp-sci",
                            "psych", "psych",
                            "history", "history"]})

bar = Bar(x, values='enrolments', label='class', stack='gender',
         title="Number of students enrolled per class",
         legend='top_right',bar_width=1.0)
output_file("myPlot.html")
show(bar)
```

[image: stacked bar plot]

Comment: Thanks! Just what I need!

Comment: `bokeh.charts` is deprecated and removed now. Do you have any alternative for this?

Answer (score 30):

Also, I have found another way to do this (with pandas):

`df.groupby(['feature1', 'feature2']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)`

Source:
[making a stacked barchart in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683654/making-a-stacked-barchart-in-pandas)

Comment: What does the `size()` and `unstack()` do? Thanks.

Comment: simple and clean!

Answer (score 2):

size produces a column with a simple row count for that grouping, its what produces the values for the y axis. unstack produces the row and column information necessary for matplotlib to create the stacked bar graph.

Essentially it takes

```
>>> s
one  a   1.0
     b   2.0
two  a   3.0
     b   4.0
```

and produces:

```
>>> s.unstack(level=-1)
     a   b
one  1.0  2.0
two  3.0  4.0
```