# plot grouped information from survey

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with a variable of interest (categorical, here `Yes`, `No`, etc.) and a grouping variable (see below):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'ID': range(100),
    'group': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 100),
    'Response':np.random.choice(['Yes','No','Other', np.nan], 100)})
```

From this, I would like to retrieve and plot the accumulated data per group in a bar plot.

In detail: for group `A`, the percentage of `Yes`, `No`, etc., the same for group by.
The command `df['Response'].groupby(df['group']).value_counts()` already gives me this output:

```
group  Response
A      Other       14
       No           8
       Yes          8
       nan          8
B      Other       11
       nan         11
       No           5
       Yes          4
C      No           9
       Yes          9
       nan          7
       Other        6
Name: Response, dtype: int64
```

This is what I want but I can't find a way to plot it appropriately (in matplotlib or seaborn) and am unsure if this is an issue of data transformation or visualization.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971467/bar-plotting-grouped-pandas) question is asking about something similar but I can't get it to work with `unstack`:

```
df = df['group'].unstack(0, fill_value = 0)
```

gives

> AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels'

and

```
df = df['group'].unstack(0, fill_value = 0)
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

only plots the `ID` (ungrouped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do `unstack` without select the `columns` , the `groupby` output is `Series`, and notice you are using `Series` `groupby` not `pd.DataFrame.groupby`

```
df['Response'].groupby(df['group']).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

```
type(df['Response'].groupby(df['group']).value_counts())
Out[207]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: excellent, thank you. Using `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)`, I get the desired plot. How do I scale from absolute numbers to percentages in this plot (the groups are of different sizes)?

Comment: @Ivo yw :-) happy coding

Comment: @Ivo pass normalized in value_counts as True

Answer (score 1):

I think better is use grouping by column in `string` and get column after `groupby` for processing:

```
df1 = df.groupby('group')['Response'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Alternative is use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['group'], df['Response'])
```

For remove index and columns names is possible use your solution or [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
df1.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None).plot.bar(stacked=True)

#pandas bellow
#df1.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

---

Your solution [is mainly syntactic sugar for the alternative and much more verbose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#dataframe-column-selection-in-groupby), obviously is using if need process column before, e.g need lowercase of column `Response`:

```
df1 = df['Response'].str.lower().groupby(df['group']).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

First solution is possible, but need 2 rows:

```
df['Response'] = df['Response'].str.lower()
df1 = df.groupby('group')['Response'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

EDIT:

For scaling use `normalize=True` in [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
.value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: excellent, thank you. Using `df1.plot.bar(stacked=True)`, I get the desired plot. How do I scale from absolute numbers to percentages in this plot (the groups are of different sizes)?

Comment: @Ivo - For scaling change `value_counts()` to `value_counts(normalize=True)`